# what is return value from print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); command mean

Tags: php, pdo

```
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); //
```

Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => sqlite )

Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => sqlite [2] => sqlite2 )

What is difference beween these 2 output

Thanks everone for answer my innocent question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/it/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php

> This function returns all currently available PDO drivers which can be used in DSN parameter of PDO::__construct()

The sqlite driver is SQLite 3, while sqlite2 is SQLite 2 and therefore is older.
The SQLite 2 driver for PDO is provided primarily to make it easier to import legacy SQLite 2 database files into an application that uses the faster, more efficient SQLite 3 driver.